# Ntlk & Python, plotting ROC curve

Tags: python, nlp, machine-learning, nltk

I am using nltk with Python and I would like to plot the ROC curve of my classifier (Naive Bayes). Is there any function for plotting it or should I have to track the True Positive rate and False Positive rate ?

It would be great if someone would point me to some code already doing it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyROC looks simple enough: [tutorial](http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2010/09/tools-for-machine-learning-performance.html), [source code](http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2010/09/tools-for-machine-learning-performance.html)

This is how it would work with the NLTK naive bayes classifier:

```
# class labels are 0 and 1
labeled_data = [
    (1, featureset_1),
    (0, featureset_2),
    (1, featureset_3),
    # ...
]

# naive_bayes is your already trained classifier,
# preferrably not on the data you're testing on :)

from pyroc import ROCData

roc_data = ROCData(
    (label, naive_bayes.prob_classify(featureset).prob(1))
    for label, featureset
    in labeled_data
)
roc_data.plot()
```

**Edits:**

- ROC is for binary classifiers only. If you have three classes, you can measure the performance of your positive and negative class separately (by counting the other two classes as 0, like you proposed).
- The library expects the output of a decision function as the second value of each tuple. It then tries all possible thresholds, e.g. f(x) >= 0.8 => classify as 1, and plots a point for each threshold (that's why you get a curve in the end). So if your classifier guesses class 0, you actually want a value closer to zero. That's why I proposed `.prob(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, there are a couple of things I don't understand: 1) I have 3 classes, named "P","N" and "?" (Positive, Negative and Neutral), is it ok if I assign to the positive class the number 1 and to the negative,neutral class the 0? 2) Shouldn't it be "naive_bayes.prob_classify(featureset).prob(label))" ? (that is, passing the probability of the label instead of the positive class)

Comment: @DT: I edited my answer - tell me if it isn't clear or I said something wrong!

Comment: Thanks again! The first dot in the edit is clear. About the second dot, I understood how a ROC curve is plotted (thanks for the clear explanation), but I want to double check this: if 1=positive and 0=negative, and you use `prob(1)` you are plotting the ROC curve that shows the performance for positive classification, right ?

Comment: based on python2 not very practical now; using http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py instead