# Plotting ROC curve for NLTK classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, roc

This would have answered my question, but it appears it is from 2011 and the method has been deprecated: [Ntlk & Python, plotting ROC curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192455/ntlk-python-plotting-roc-curve)

What is the best way to get a ROC curve on a classifier I've trained? I have a nltk NaiveBayes classifier trained called `naive_bayes`, and `naive_bayes.classify(feature)` either returns `pos` or `neg`(and of course I can get the probabilities with `prob_classify(feature)`). I have a test set of feature sets that I'd like to use to generate my curves.

I heard `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` might do, but I could not get it to work.

I'd really appreciate a code example if at all possible.

Comment: To generate a ROC curve, you need a vector of probabilities (not just pos/neg).

Comment: Yep, I get those when I run `naive_bayes.prob_classify()`, I was more just saying that I have two outputs